# how to replace a pattern in only one file from current directory

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose I have 4 files with .txt extension in current directory, and i want to replace a pattern from only one file. Condition is we dont know name of file and replacement must be done in only one file. Other files should not be affected.
example:

> user/home>ls -lart *.txt

a1.txt
b1.txt
c1.txt
d1.txt

there is one word "Day" in all of these files, i want to replace it with "Night" in only one file without affecting other files. How can I do this?

I tried below, but it replaces the pattern in all 4 files.

find . -type f -name "*.txt"|xargs sed 's/Day/Night/g'

Comment: Which one (in the 4 files) do you want to replace the word?

Comment: any one, but we dont know file name.

Comment: how would you know in which file the change is made, if you don't know where you want the change to happen.

Comment: what is your usecase ...question should be framed correctly. Please refer ...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have updated the question, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for a file with the pattern and replace inplace with the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i 's/Day/Night/' $(grep -l "Day" *.txt | head -1 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: Whene  one of the answers work for you, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.

```
for file in *.txt; do 
    sed 's/Day/Night/g' "$file";
break; done
```

should be both fast and robust.

Comment: Thanks for your response